# Upsert query on postgres SQL while checking if need to keep old values or insert new values?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, upsert

I have a postgres SQL query where I want to do upsert.
My `pk1, pk2` columns are composite primary key. And I want to update 3 columns `dk1, dk2, timek` if there is a conflict with the primary key constraint.
Also when I update the columns on conflict, say `timek` column, then I need to check if the new value is less than old value and choose accordingly if need to use old value or new value.
Here is the query I have but it throws error.
I am new to postgres SQL, please suggest what's wrong?

```
INSERT INTO data_reports (pk1, pk2, dk1, dk2, dk3, timek, valuek)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  
ON CONFLICT (pk1, pk2) DO UPDATE SET 
dk1 = EXCLUDED.dk1, 
dk2 = CASE WHEN (dk2 < EXCLUDED.dk2) THEN EXCLUDED.dk2 ELSE dk2 END), // I believe dk2 (existing value in DB) is not selected but how to do that
timek = CASE WHEN (timek < EXCLUDED.timek) THEN EXCLUDED.timek ELSE timek END);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can refer to pre-update column values by specifying the table name: e.g. `data_reports.dk2`.
2. Open and close parentheses, There are 5 `(`s and 7 `)`s.
3. Start a comment with `--`, or enclose a comment with `/*` and `*/`.

```
INSERT INTO data_reports (pk1,pk2,dk1,dk2,dk3,timek,valuek)
VALUES (1,1,9,9,9,9,9)
ON CONFLICT (pk1,pk2) DO
UPDATE
SET
    dk1 = EXCLUDED.dk1,
    dk2 =
    (CASE
        WHEN (data_reports.dk2 < EXCLUDED.dk2) THEN EXCLUDED.dk2
        ELSE data_reports.dk2
    END),
    timek =
    (CASE
        WHEN (data_reports.timek < EXCLUDED.timek) THEN EXCLUDED.timek
        ELSE data_reports.timek
    END);
```

Comment: Thanks @shoek, was looking for pre-update column values to access. It works!

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI: You could simplify by replacing the CASE expression by the LEAST function:

```
insert into data_reports (pk1,pk2,dk1,dk2,dk3,timek,valuek)
values (1,1,9,9,9,9,9)
on conflict (pk1,pk2) do
update
set
    dk1 = excluded.dk1,
    dk2 = least(data_reports.dk2, excluded.dk2),
    timek = least(data_reports.timek, excluded.timek);
```

Comment: Thanks! @Belayer This is indeed the more better answer, but as per the question I wanted to use the CASE ELSE THEN. :)